# How to find occurrences of certain string everytime X value comes on in a csv in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, find-occurrences

I have created a .csv with data on every player drafted in the NHL for every year since 1979. The 9000-ish lines in my csv look like this:

```
1979,Rob Ramage (D),ON
1979,Perry Turnbull (LW),AB
1979,Raymond Bourque (D),QC
2017,Kristian Røykås Marthinsen (LW),NOR
2017,William Reilly (D),ON
```

What I am trying to find, is how many time each province/state/country comes in for every year. For example, how many time "QC" appears in the third row when the first row is 1979, and place it in another csv. Note that all lines in my csv are sorted by year, meaning that my first lines all start with 1979, then 1980, then 1981, etc.

After grouping the results for some states, provinces and countries together, I would like to be able to come up with an outcome like:

```
1979,32,94,36,4
1980,37,84,40,10
1981,40,90,34,22
1982,39,102,18,10
...
```

The first row would be the year and then, each time that each of the string (QC, ON, NOR, etc.) appears for that value. As you can see, I have no use for the players' names for this application.

My question is, how can I find the occurrences of a specific string in lines that have a certain value in them? I feel like this should not be too complicated to do, but I simply do not know where to start, as I am pretty new to programming.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you permitted to use a 3rd party library, e.g. `pandas` ?

Answer (score 0):

### Plain Python

This can be done using only `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    origin_count_by_year = {}

    for line in f:
        year, _, origin = map(str.strip, line.split(','))

        if year not in origin_count_by_year:
            origin_count_by_year[year] = Counter()

        origin_count_by_year[year][origin] += 1
```

With the data you provided, this generate the following `dict`.

```
{
    '1979': Counter({'ON': 1, 'AB': 1, 'QC': 1}),
    '2017': Counter({'NOR': 1, 'ON': 1})
}
```

### Alternatives

The above is good for a short project, but if you intend to scale it, parsing a *csv* file is the wrong approach.

The best approach is probably to use [panda](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) which is a library specifically for data analysis. It will help you scalling by [parsing your csv file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [returning a `DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe).

A second approach is to use a database instead of a *csv* file. Using the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) standard library, you can query players by year and country and count them.